# Custom folder icons for IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

This documentation of IntelliJ SDK ([link](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/work_with_icons_and_images.html)) describes how to load icons for custom file types, actions and tool windows, but does not mention folder icons. Is it possible from a plugin to modify default icons for particular folders in a project's structure?

Comment: try to explain your question here itself, instead of providing an external link ,which might go down anytime.

Comment: for anyone arriving here by looking for a plugin that allows to customize folder icons based on pattern - see this https://gitlab.com/coderpillr/jetbrains/support/icons/-/issues/1#note_437050366

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use the com.intellij.ide.IconProvider interface to provide a custom icon for any element, including directories (represented by PsiDirectory instances).

Comment: I have got a hint from someone else that I should implement FileIconProvider interface and then register it as an ExtentionPoint via plugin.xml. Which interface is more preferable? Would using [IconLoader](https://github.com/bulenkov/iconloader) be a good idea to load the required resources from the classpath?

Comment: For your task, you can use either of the two interfaces. Using IconLoader is indeed the correct thing to do.